# Reusing SAML assertion

Tags: salesforce, saml, f5

I am implementing single sign on with multiple SPs. Here is my basic understanding:

1) Browser(User) requests resource from Service Provider (SP). 
2) SP Redirects (with SAML Request) to Identity Provider (IdP).
3) Since it is first login, User gives the (IdP) his/her valid credentials.
4) IdP then redirects Browser (with SAML Response which includes SAML token) to the SP page.

Now let's say I have Service Provider A and Service Provider B. A user has completed the step about for Service Provider A. From service provider A (salesforce.com in my scenario), I have written a **server-side method** which instantiates a callout to an endpoint on Service Provider B. Is it possible to re-use the SAML assertion in this case? I.e. will service provider B trust the backend method?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to customize Service Provider B in order for it to accept, understand and interpret the `Assertion` obtained by Service Provider A. It would certainly not work out-of-the-box.

The `SAML Assertion` included in the `SAML Response` to Service Provider A contains pieces of data which correlate it with the original `SAML Request` and define recipients of the message (for example using elements `SubjectConfirmationData` and `Audience`). The Service Provider B would need to ignore values in these fields, as it is actually not the indented recipient of the `Assertion`.

The problem of how to broker trust between two machines where user's identity is asserted by an identity provider can be solved with multiple standard approaches. One is to use a `Session Token Service` (based on [WS-Trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Trust)) which defines how to request and issue tokens to 3rd party services. Another is to use [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). You could of course also simply authenticate Service Provider A to Service Provider B using a custom scheme with a password, HMAC, ...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer - no if Service Provider B is implemented as a standard SAML 2.0 SP.

SAML 2.0 assertions are "targeted" and signed. They have a specified audience and a recipient URL. You cannot change them without breaking the signature. 
The assertion received by SP A contains the name of SP A as audience and the ACS end point of SP A as recipient URL. Such an assertion will not be accepted by SP B.

What prevents you from just calling SP B in a standard way and let it initiate its own SAML 2.0 flow? Another option would be to perform an IDP-initiated SSO flow for SP B. Not all IDP implementations support it though.